# split a string twice, but the second time i got an error

Tags: java, string, split

I need to split a string twice in order to apply a metric on an OWL file. first time it's ok,and the array parts get two elements,but the second time the array firstDataSet is empty and i got this error : Exception in thread "main"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1. any help please?

```
String line;
    String[] parts = new String [4];
    String[] firstDataSet = new String [4];
    String[] secondDataSet = new String [4];
    double externalSameAsCounter = 0;
    double externalEdgeCounter = 0;
    double ratio = 0;

    try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        line = br.readLine();
        while ((line = br.readLine())!= null ){
            if(line.contains("->") && line.contains(".")){
                 parts = line.split("->");
                 firstDataSet = parts[0].split(".");
                 if(parts[1].contains("http")){
                    secondDataSet = parts[1].split(".");
                 }
                 if(((firstDataSet[1].toLowerCase()).contains(secondDataSet[1].toLowerCase()))){
                     externalEdgeCounter = externalEdgeCounter + 1;
                 }
            }
            if(line.contains("owl:sameAs")){
                 parts = line.split("->");
                 firstDataSet = parts[0].split(".");
                 secondDataSet = parts[1].split(".");
                 if(!((firstDataSet[1].toLowerCase()).contains(secondDataSet[1].toLowerCase()))){
                     externalSameAsCounter = externalSameAsCounter +1;
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println(
            "Unable to open file");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error reading file");  
    }
    ratio = (double)(externalSameAsCounter / externalEdgeCounter);
    return ratio;
```

Comment: What line is associated with the error? It should tell you in the crash log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When regular expressions, `.` means any character and if you split on `.` it will not do what you expect.  I suggest trying `"[.]"` which means `.` literally.

Comment: @sdzivanovich If you mean `"\\."` then yes, I just didn't want to get into why it needs to be `"\\."` and not `"\."` in Java.

Answer (score 3):

In the second `if` block, you're splitting on `"->"`, but you have no guarantee the string contains that substring, because all you checked was whether the string contained `"owl:sameAs"`.

Comment: Same problem occurs in the first block there is no guarantee that `parts[0]` contains `"."`

Comment: i'm working on a specific file, i'm sure about having '->' and '.' by using '[.]' instead of '.' it works correctly. thank you :)